# Use function to transform variables inside group_by to factors

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

The following function uses `dplyr`'s `group_by` to get the number of categories over a set of user defined variables:

```
datos_calidad <- function(datos, lista) {
  datos %>% group_by(across({{lista}}), .drop = FALSE) %>%  
      summarise(RNP = n())
}
```

Here is some dummy data to show how it works:

```
 sample_data <- structure(list(CL_REGION = c("CHL10", "CHL10", "CHL01", "CHL01", 
"CHL10", "CHL10", "CHL10", "CHL01", "CHL01", "CHL10", "CHL10", 
"CHL01", "CHL01", "CHL01", "CHL01", "CHL01", "CHL10", "CHL01", 
"CHL10", "CHL01", "CHL01", "CHL10", "CHL01", "CHL10", "CHL01", 
"CHL01", "CHL01", "CHL01", "CHL01"), CL_RAMA_ECO = c("ISIC4_CAENES12_R", 
"ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", 
"ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", 
"ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", 
"ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_U", 
"ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", 
"ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", 
"ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R", "ISIC4_CAENES12_R"
)), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now, I use it:

```
datos_calidad(sample_data, c("CL_REGION", "CL_RAMA_ECO")) %>% arrange(RNP)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   CL_REGION [2]
  CL_REGION CL_RAMA_ECO        RNP
  <chr>     <chr>            <int>
1 CHL10     ISIC4_CAENES12_U     1
2 CHL10     ISIC4_CAENES12_R    10
3 CHL01     ISIC4_CAENES12_R    18
```

However, that output does not account for combination of categories with no data. The only way to get that information is specifying inside `group_by` that the variables are factors like this:

```
sample_data %>% group_by(CL_REGION = as.factor(CL_REGION), CL_RAMA_ECO = as.factor(CL_RAMA_ECO), .drop = FALSE) %>%  
  summarise(RNP = n()) %>% arrange(RNP) 

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   CL_REGION [2]
  CL_REGION CL_RAMA_ECO        RNP
  <fct>     <fct>            <int>
1 CHL01     ISIC4_CAENES12_U     0
2 CHL10     ISIC4_CAENES12_U     1
3 CHL10     ISIC4_CAENES12_R    10
4 CHL01     ISIC4_CAENES12_R    18
```

My question is how do I transform the vector of character variables inside `datos_calidad()`'s `lista` argument to transform each one of them to a vector variable like in the second command. I've tried different ways but none of them worked so far.

**EDIT**: Use of `across` is not mandatory, but the user has to be able to input 1 to n variables inside the `datos_calidad()`'s `lista` argument.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also transform the variables into a factor within the group_by:

```
datos_calidad <- function(datos, lista) {
  datos %>% group_by(across(all_of(lista), as.factor), .drop = FALSE) %>%  
    summarise(RNP = n())
}
datos_calidad(sample_data, c("CL_REGION", "CL_RAMA_ECO")) %>% arrange(RNP)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   CL_REGION [2]
  CL_REGION CL_RAMA_ECO        RNP
  <fct>     <fct>            <int>
1 CHL01     ISIC4_CAENES12_U     0
2 CHL10     ISIC4_CAENES12_U     1
3 CHL10     ISIC4_CAENES12_R    10
4 CHL01     ISIC4_CAENES12_R    18
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to create the full combinations with `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
sample_data %>% 
    mutate(n = 1) %>%
    complete(CL_REGION, CL_RAMA_ECO, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    group_by(CL_REGION, CL_RAMA_ECO) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(n), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  CL_REGION CL_RAMA_ECO          n
  <chr>     <chr>            <dbl>
1 CHL01     ISIC4_CAENES12_R    18
2 CHL01     ISIC4_CAENES12_U     0
3 CHL10     ISIC4_CAENES12_R    10
4 CHL10     ISIC4_CAENES12_U     1
```

---

Or after using the OP's function, add the `complete`

```
datos_calidad(sample_data, c("CL_REGION", "CL_RAMA_ECO")) %>% 
   arrange(RNP) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   complete(CL_REGION, CL_RAMA_ECO, fill = list(RNP = 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  CL_REGION CL_RAMA_ECO        RNP
#  <chr>     <chr>            <dbl>
#1 CHL01     ISIC4_CAENES12_R    18
#2 CHL01     ISIC4_CAENES12_U     0
#3 CHL10     ISIC4_CAENES12_R    10
#4 CHL10     ISIC4_CAENES12_U     1
```